# Obtener un campo de una respuesta luego de hacer un post para poder utilizar ese campo en otras peticiones

Tags: typescript

```
let response = this.registrarUsuariosService.postNuevoUsuario(this.usuario)
  .subscribe( resp =>{
    
    console.log('Respuesta',resp);
    this.idUser = resp; 
  } );
  console.log('Usuario',this.usuario);
  console.log('User id',this.idUser);
  console.log('Response',response)
  return response;
```

}

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el campo que necesito sacar es addgeneralpepoldata que esta en Respuesta e igualarlo al this.idUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let response = this.registrarUsuariosService.postNuevoUsuario(this.usuario)
  .subscribe( resp =>{
    console.log('Respuesta',resp);
    this.idUser = resp;
    this.idUserUsar = this.idUser[0]?.addgeneralpepoldata;
    console.log('Id usuario', this.idUserUsar)
  } );
  return response;
```

solucionado muchas gracias

Comment: favor de votar por la respuesta si te fue util, gracias

Answer (score 0):

la pregunta no esta muy clara de que es lo que quieres pero si lo que deseas es sacar la información de addgeneralpepoldata que viene de la peticion sería de la siguiente manera

```javascript
let response = this.registrarUsuariosService.postNuevoUsuario(this.usuario).subscribe((res) => {
   console.log('Respuesta',resp);
   // obtener el atributo addgeneralpepoldata

   // NOTA: como se puede apreciar el la captura de pantalla
   // la respuesta es un arreglo entonces por eso recorremos el primer item
   console.log('addgeneralpepoldata: ', resp[0].addgeneralpepoldata);
   // ó
   console.log('addgeneralpepoldata: ', resp[0]['addgeneralpepoldata']);
},(err) => {

});
```